# How to get network image height and width using Glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am trying to get height and width of network image. I am using Glide to display image.

Code I've used in Java is:

```java
Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
 .asBitmap()
 .load(path)
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                 Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
         int w = bitmap.getWidth();
         int h = bitmap.getHeight()
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
 });
```

How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Comment: You can convert your java code to Kotlin directly using Android Studio. If is not recommended for large files, but for small code chunks it is fine and I think it is also a good resource to learn the Kotlin language.

Comment: Actually, I've already tried it, but not converted automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Glide.with(context.applicationContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(path)
                .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap?>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap?>?) {
                        val w = bitmap.width
                        val h = bitmap.height
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    }

                })
```